# In spring manage threads created by one controller's different instances

Tags: spring, controller, ffmpeg, threadpool

I have written a controller to deal with video upload. The hard part for me is to convert the video type to both mp4 and webm. I chose to new a thread in my controller and the thread will new a process which is a video convert software called "ffmpeg".

The problem is that this thread will occupy too much resources(at least 25% CPU usage). So I guess I have to make these threads created by different controller instances execute in a shared queue. It is terrible to have these threads in concurrent execution.

It seems that the taskExecutor in Spring can only manage threads created by one controller instance. And is there any way to manage threads among threads created by one controller class but different instances? It seems like a public or shared thread pool..

Comment: What about ExecutorService from which you make fixed threadpool of 2 threads and add the two conversions to the pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly how your project is set up, but that's what I meant if it makes sense.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/convert")
public class UploadController {
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView processVideoConvert() throws InterruptedException {

    final ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("convert");

    threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          //first conversion
        }
    });

    threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         //second conversion
        }
    });

    threadPool.shutdown();
    //threadPool.awaitTermination(500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Comment: It really saves me! Thanks a lot ! And by the way, is there any problem if I comment the statement "threadPool.shutdown();" ?

Comment: Otherwise if the num of threads is over 2, it will always throw Reject Exception even when the tasks in the pool are completed.

Comment: Hmm I am not exactly sure, I believe you actually must have shutdown together with awaitTermination, so after shutdown the await makes sure all the tasks are done. So you would have to uncomment the termination, but remove the timeout unless you have some specific time how long you want to wait before the tasks are terminated.

Comment: Actually the requirement is that the video upload controller can handle the request anytime. So I think the number of tasks is supposed to be infinite ^_^ Then can I just do not shundown this shared threadpool?

Comment: Fixed thread pool only accepts 2 tasks at any time. Shutdown is called to say that do the pool is not accepting any new tasks. I think it is a good practice to call shutdown and then awaitTermination, just set the timeout to max. This ensures you that all the threads have finished. `awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);`